# Disable Deployment Approval Pending notification

Tags: azure-devops, devops

i have disable release pending approval emails. But these emails are not disabled. I am still receiving

emails  for pending approval azure devops[image]

Email received
[image]

How can we disable receiving emails for approval.?

Comment: Hey Ahmad you need to check your release pipeline approval setting.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I notice that you disable notification at the project level.

Tested with the same settings and I could reproduce this issue.

Since personal notifications apply to **all projects**, this could be the cause of this problem.

To solve this issue, you could disable the Personal Notifications in `User Settings -> Notification`.

[image]

[image]

In this case,  this notification will be disabled.